# Open an email message from Flex with the body of the email message populated

Tags: apache-flex, email, flex4.5

I want to set up an email from Flex so that when I press a button it opens a new message from the default mail program. (In most cases this will be Outlook). I have got something that uses mailTo: and open an new message with the to email address filled in. What I want is to populate the message part of the email. I am not overly concerned with who is in the to: line. I just want the message part populated.

Is this possible in Flex?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2006/11/21/Creating-Web-Page-and-Email-Links-In-A-Flex-Application

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=url_requests_4.html

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the links. They only tell me how to create a new email with the to field populated with an email address. I am specifically looking at trying to get data into the body of the message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sample to populate the email body

```
 var mailMsg:URLRequest = new URLRequest('mailto:' + recipients);
 var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();               
 variables.subject = mailSubject;
 variables.body = mailBody;
 mailMsg.data = variables;
 mailMsg.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
 navigateToURL(mailMsg, "_self");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer StephenNYC

Comment: I did the same but my message is not properly formatted . I wanted 
Name              xxxxxxxxxxx
Last                 xxxxxxxxxxx

But i am getting like this:
Name              xxxxxxxxxxx
Last               xxxxxxxxxxxx
Though it has same number of characters on left. 
Perfect way is to Table format or use monospace font. But how to do so????